# Find string before uppercase letter and after

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I don't know how to get the string before the second uppercase letter.

Example string:

```
 - Støtfanger foran BMW E90 05-08 M3
 - Støtfanger foran VW SCIROCCO 08-04.14 R STYLE black grille
 - Støtfanger bak VW SCIROCCO 08-04.14 R STYLE
 - Eyebrows Audi TT 99-06 R8
 - Støtfanger MITSUBISHI LANCER 09-15 EVO STYLE
```

I need to get: `Støtfanger foran`, and second (car model):`BMW E90 05-08 M3`

I dont know how to split it.

I think it's best to use regex, but I dont know how to create it.

Comment: There's no `BMW E90 05-08 M3` in provided text....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ex = 'Støtfanger foran VW SCIROCCO 08-04.14 R STYLE black grille'


def split_second_upper(string):
    second_upper = False
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isupper() and i != 0:
            second_upper = True
        if second_upper:
            return string[0:i], string[i:]

name, car = split_second_upper(ex)
print(name)
print(car)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
str = "Støtfanger foran VW SCIROCCO 08-04.14 R STYLE black grille"
for index,element in enumerate(str): 
        if(ord(element) >= 65 and ord(element)<=90 and index >0):
            print(str[0:index])
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Try this:

```
second_upper = False
for i, char in enumerate(string):
  if second_upper:
    return string[0:i], string[i:]
  if char.isupper():
    second_upper = True
```

Don't forget to test it.

Comment: I can't install enum
from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution'

Comment: Change `enum` to `enumerate` - it's built-in.

Comment: @S3DEV is right. I'm a little rusty on Python so I misremembered the name of the function.